# Quickest/best way to load a large image ( using Glide )

Tags: java, android, image, android-glide

I am developing a Android application that display's images loaded from the sdcard.
I use the mediastore to populate a recyclerview.
If the user would click a image in the recyclerview i would like to open a activity that shows the image in full size.

When the clicked item is a huge image it takes 4/5 seconds to load.
I noticed some applications can somehow load them instantly(quickpic, google photos).
How do they do this and or what is the best practise?

I am using Glide for the async loading and caching.

I tried the glide function that loads a thumbnail first and loads the full image in the background.
I tried resizing and subsampling the image.

And thats about all the techniques i could find.

Some code i tried:

```
 Glide.with(this)
                .load(getUri().toString())
                .asBitmap()                     .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESULT)
                .priority(Priority.IMMEDIATE)
                .dontAnimate()
                .thumbail(0.1f)
                .override(height,width)
                .info(imageView
)
```

Comment: May i ask you how huge do you mean ? 20MB jpg ?

Comment: @MahdiRafatjah yes for instance

Comment: Just use override. Remove others